# Android Toolbar clicks running all tasks

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I've got a Android app where there's a few icons on the toolbar. When I click on the icon `R.id.barcode` it does run, but it will also call the `refreshList` method which is set up to be run when a different icon is clicked on the toolbar.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.barcode:
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BarcodeScanner.class);
            startActivity(i);

        case R.id.refresh:
            refreshList();

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I can't find where I'm going wrong, as other results, like this][1](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1743642&seqNum=4) are showing this as a case statement, but I can't see why it would not be working as expected.

Comment: in switch statement you forgot to break.!!

Comment: Oops. Stupid me, you're totally right. That's fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `break;` statements in each of your `case` statements.

From the docs:

> All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered.

See the example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Comment: Yes, you're totally right. Stupid little mistake, didn't even pick up on that. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it fixed! Would you mind accepting my answer as correct if you've got it figured out?

Comment: Sure, was just waiting on it letting me. Done now

Comment: Woops, sorry to be antsy. It is a rare opportunity where I can offer up the solution :)

Comment: No problem, I would be the same!